# Why we can't apply edge loop on mesh if we applied bevel first

Tags: modeling

Some times I noticed that we can't apply edge loop on mesh if we applied bevel why it is happening? It's bothering me to model as I want to. I guess it's happening because of geometric reasons please help me to understand what rocket science is happening there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you bevel it can create ngons (faces with more than 4 vertices that are no longer quads), and you can't automatically create edge loops through ngons because it can't guess what opposite edge it is supposed to cut through. But you can cut with knife and recreate quads from your ngons.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your valuable time I appreciate your knowledge.